# При выводе в консоль добавляется отступ в конце. Допустим, ввожу 666 появляется 'six hundred and sixty six ' Отступ в конце надо убрать

Tags: javascript

```
    var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
    var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];
    
    
        if ((num = num.toString()).length > 3) return 'overflow';
        n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
        if (!n) return; var str = '';
        str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
        str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + '' : '';
        return str;
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ...
  return str.trim();
}
```

*(Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 26.)*

Comment: Спасибо большое, совсем забыл про этот метод

Comment: @PABLO99 Пожалуйста. Успехов. "Галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Убрать пробелы в `a`, если они там только для того, чтобы выводить их перед *hundred*

```
var a = ['','one','two','three','four', 'five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']; // тут убрали пробелы
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];


if ((num = num.toString()).length > 3) return 'overflow';
n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
if (!n) return; var str = '';
str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + ' hundred ' : ''; // тут добавили пробел
str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + '' : '';
return str;
```